# How can I learn how to use a stroke-keyboard?

Tags: stroke-order, strokes

I use Pinyin -> 汉子 keyboard normally, but when I see a character I don’t know, I wish I could type it by sight, without copying and pasting it to translate, or selecting it to look it up.

I have this stroke keyboard:

[image]

This explains it:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke_count_method

I know I will just need to study and practice it, but is there a short primer or rule of thumb?

I am unable to figure out the stroke order for 我.

Is there a good place to look them up?

Answer (score 1):

Try [here](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%B0%B1) for the stroke order of characters:

Or mdbg.net

On mdbg.net, enter a character. Click on the character, then the character will be shown larger. Click on the 3 dots icon next to the character, you will see more choices. Click on the paint brush icon and a window will open and draw the character stroke by stroke.

dict.baidu.com also shows the stroke order of characters.

On my phone I have Hanping Pro. You can draw characters with your finger. That is not too fussy about the stroke order, when you see a new character and you don't know exactly how to write it.

Hanping Pro also shows the stroke order of characters.

I'm sure there are many other places to go to find characters and stroke orders!

Answer (score 0):

No. It is designed for experienced Chinese user to input so it must be input in order.

However, many characters have more than one way to write(one is offical but many Chinese people may use other ways) and most keyboard will support it so you will have a better chance to correctly input it.

You may check the HanZi you need in website like http://bs.kaishicha.com/